# How to delete a row and a column

Tags: r

Libraries I use:

````
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(statsr)



```{r}
factor_sc <- table(gss1$class, gss1$getahead) 
factor_sc <- addmargins(factor_sc)
factor_sc 
```
````

I write this and the output is:

```
               Hard Work Both Equally Luck Or Help Other   Sum
  Lower Class        1063          368          299     0  1730
  Working Class     10229         3221         1870     0 15320
  Middle Class       9914         3624         1612     0 15150
  Upper Class         701          265          100     0  1066
  No Class              0            0            0     0     0
  Sum               21907         7478         3881     0 33266
```

---

I want to run the chi-square inference on this data so that I want to remove Others and No class.

However, I already remove them using:

````
```{r} 
gss1 <- gss %>%   filter(!is.na(getahead),
!is.na(class), class != "No Class", getahead !="Other") 
```
````

Why do `Other` and `No class` appear in my table?

Comment: Highly probably, the `gss1$class` and `gss1$getahead` columns are factor columns which contain the `Other` and `No class` levels respectively. Just doing `gss1 <- droplevels(gss1)` before the table command or using `table(droplevels(gss1$class), droplevels(gss1$getahead))` will give you the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a little misunderstanding here. `filter` is used to remove lines of your dataset. What you want here is to change your `class` to `NA` when it is `"No Class"`. `mutate` is what you need.

Try this code:

```
gss1 <- gss %>% 
  mutate(class = ifelse(class=="No Class", NA, class), 
         getahead = ifelse(getahead =="Other", NA, getahead )) %>% 
  select(class, getahead) %>% 
  table %>% 
  chisq.test
```

It is possible that you need to use `NA_character_` instead of `NA`.

You could just remove these lines and columns from `factor_sc` by writing this:

```
factor_sc[-5,-4] %>% chisq.test
```

Comment: factor_sc[-5,-4] seems wrong... If it works, then df = 3*2 = 6 but it indicates 12, which might come from the original table of 5 classes and 4 getaheads.

Comment: Without a bit of your dataset or a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), it's difficult to say. When I try on a dummy `table`, it works and df go from 9 to 4, but maybe your case is specific. What about the other code ?

Comment: I found what is the problem. The problem is on factor_sc <- add margins(factor_sc). I delete it and run the code you give and it works. Thanks!

Comment: Good for you ! (sorry, I didn't even check this function). But I still think the upper code is much better, are you sure `gss1` variable is empty ?

Answer (score 0):

Try simple df$column <- NULL for column and similar for row. 
If the attempt is to achieve something bigger good luck.